# SAS. How to overcome cell storage limit issue?

Tags: sas

I have a problem. I am pulling data from Teradata Database directly into SAS. The data looks like this:

```
id fragmentId   fragment
1     34       (some text)
2     67       (some text)
3     89       (some text) 
.......
```

The problem is that the fragment field contains text of 10 pages and even more **(30,000,000 characters)**. Thus in SAS I get the column truncated and loose data.
How can I increase the limit for a SAS column that would contain text?

(PS: I have looked up `dbmax_text` option as @Joe suggested. However, it appears that this option applies to any dbms except teradata).
How can i code it?

Comment: Need more information here, but it should be possible.  How big is the field (max char width)?

Comment: Thank you for response. I am not sure because the text column is the result of the concatenating a bunch of Teradata observations each of which has the text format. I will make a query to check it

Comment: The maximum size is 30,000,000 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teradata indeed does not support DBMAX_TEXT.  It also does not seem to support character sizes nearly as high as you list; [the doc page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/65247/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0v7nh4ylrihtin1te8xl0q3dvzv.htm) for teradata lists a maximum of 64,000 bytes; and further, SAS is only able to hold a maximum of 32767 characters in one column.

In your case, you may want to consider splitting the column in-database into 32767 byte chunks (or whatever makes logical sense for your needs).  Do that in passthrough in a view, and then read the data in from that view.

*-- Previous information (helpful for other DBMSs other than Teradata, not helpful here) --*

Odds are you need to change the `dbmax_text` option to something larger - it tends to default to 1024.

You can change it in the pull (the data step or sql query) as a dataset option, or change it in the database libname statement.

See [the documentation page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001371562.htm) for more information.

Comment: I have just figured out that the maximum number of characters is 30,000,000. What format could you suggest. How can I code it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Updated per your additional comments.